# C# ServiceStack Attribute and Swagger UI - List of complex objects

Tags: c#, servicestack, swagger-2.0

What would be the proper way of using annotation in C# for Swagger-UI in order to have a definition of complex objects listed.

For example, if we have something like this:

```
  [ApiMember(Name = "Foo", Description = "Some description", 
DataType = "List<Foo>", IsRequired = true)]    
public List<Foo> Foo {get; set;}
```

So, if I use it like that, swagger-ui will just show in documentation that this is a `List` but not link or anything to `Foo`.

I mean, it's shown properly in model \ schema, but just not listed in the field definition, is that how it's suppose to work, or it can be changed to point to exact data structure which is expected in the list \ array?

EDIT
Here's the full DTO sample:

```
[Route("/warranties", "POST", Summary = "POST New Warrantty", Notes = "Create new warranty into our system")]
public class CreateWarrantyRequest : IReturn<ApiResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "CoverageId", Description = "Coverage Id", DataType = "int", IsRequired = true)]
    public string CoverageId { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Name = "WarrantyProducts", Description = "Warranty Products", DataType = "List<WarrantyProduct>", IsRequired = true)]
    public List<WarrantyProduct> WarrantyProducts { get; set; }
}

public class WarrantyProduct
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Manufacturer", Description = "Manufacturer Name", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    [ApiMember(Name = "ProductType ", Description = "Product Type", DataType = "ProductType", IsRequired = true)]
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    [ApiMember(Name = "SerialNumber", Description = "Serial Number", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    [ApiMember(Name = "PurchasePrice", Description = "Purchase Price", DataType = "decimal", IsRequired = true)]
    public decimal PurchasePrice { get; set; }    
}
```

And this is how it looks with SwaggerFeature:
[image]

And this is how it looks with OpenApiFeature:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataType is for specifying [a known type](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types). Defining complex Types like `List<T>` is done by specifying an `array` Type with its `items` [referencing the Complex Type schema](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#response-object-examples), e.g:

```
{
  "description": "A complex object array response",
  "schema": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/VeryComplexType"
    }
  }
}
```

This is what ServiceStack does automatically without specifying the DataType, Complex Types can't be defined using `[ApiMember]`.

Comment: how come that when using SwaggerFeature I got model schema for request but when using OpenApiFeature it's not shown, and also when using OpenApiFeature it shows "undefined" for data type. Can you show some C# example for this, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @ShP They're 2 different specifications that are consumed using 2 different  versions of Swagger UI. Like I've said there is no way to define complex types using attributes, but ServiceStack already emits the appropriate complex type definition according to the Open API spec.

Comment: I am little bit confused, you said SS already emits the appropriate complex type, but in OpenApi for my object says "undefined" and it is not listed in model schema as well...

Comment: @ShP It should emit the appropriate type info by default, like my answer. If you’re seeing undefined with default behaviour (I.e without [ApiMember]) please update your question with a screenshot showing the issue and full DTO class definitions you’re using.

Comment: I have updated the initial question with DTO and print-screens, hope this helps.

Comment: @ShP You're not using the defaults, DataType needs to be either a [known Type](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types) or left unspecified.

Comment: O.o oh ok, my bad, it's working fine now! Thanks for your help once again. :)