# Generate correct documentation for a list of complex objects using ServiceStack / OpenAPI spec 2.0

Tags: c#, swagger, servicestack, openapi

I have the following API, defined using ServiceStack, for which the documentation is not generating correctly.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Route("/users", "PUT")]
public class UpdateUsersRequest : IReturn<List<User>>
{
    [ApiMember(DataType = "array", Description = "Users to be updated", ParameterType = "body", IsRequired = true)]
    public List<User> UsersToUpdate { get; set; }
}

public class UsersService : Service
{
    public List<User> Put(UpdateUsersRequest request)
    {
        return new List<User>();
    }
}
```

If I specify the ApiMember attribute (as shown above), I get the following documentation, where the description is shown correctly, but the example value is incorrect.
[image: Documentation with ApiMember attribute]

Also, ServiceStack is never able to parse the body (see examples below) and I always get a *SerializationException* with a message:

> Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type
> 'UpdateUsersRequest', got string starting with: ["{","
> \"UpdateUsersRequest\": {","        \"Us"*.

Example 1: only the array.

```
[ { "Name": "string", "Id": 0 } ]
```

Example 2: the property.

```
{ "UsersToUpdate": [ { "Name": "string", "Id": 0 } ] }
```

Example 3: complete object.

```
{ 
  "UpdateUsersRequest": { 
    "UsersToUpdate": [ 
      { 
        "Name": "string", 
        "Id": 0
      }
    ]
  } 
}
```

I also tried not adding the ApiMember attribute, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082048/c-sharp-servicestack-attribute-and-swagger-ui-list-of-complex-objects). This generates the example correctly, and I can use it to send values to my request. However, there is no description shown, and I get an extra row for the *UsersToUpdate* property.

[image: Documentation without ApiMember attribute]

If I specify any value here, it again results in a *SerializationException*.

My question: *How can I generate the documentation correctly, such that the description and examples are shown correctly, and I do not end up with an extra useless row?*

Note: I also tried creating a wrapper object around the list, but that doesn't work either and again results in a *SerializationException*. This will likely not be an acceptable solution as it will end up changing the existing customer scripts to execute the APIs, but mentioning it here anyway.

Comment: The error suggests that you are passing a collection rather than an object when you try to call the service.

Comment: @tomredfern I've tried all combinations, end up getting the same error unfortunately.